How to write "Cube group" in more than 3 dimensions?
I am considering a subgroup of $O(3)$, which satisfied that remain the reference frame still and just change the signs and directions. For example, a $90 ^\circ$ rotation around the z axis makes $x\rightarrow y, y\rightarrow -x$.
In other words, this group is generated by the rotations of $90^\circ, 180^\circ, 270^\circ$ around x,y,z axis , the reflection of x,y,z axis, and their combinations. This group is called "cube group" in 3 dimensions, e.g. in Wiki. It contains 48 elements, and isomorphic to $\mathcal{S}_4 \times \mathcal{Z}_2$.
How could I promote this group to higher dimensions?
Here are some steps I tried:
In 2d, this subgroup should contains 8 elements: 4 (rotations) times 2 (reflections). Or, we could view the 2d frame as four directions (x,-x,y,-y). In order to construct a new frame, we first choose one of four as new x', and then choose one of the lasting two directions those vertical to x' as new y'.
In 3d, we know that the group has 48 elements. We could also use the steps above:first choose one of six(x,-x,y,-y,z,-z) as new x'. Then choose one of the remaining 4 directions those are vertical to x' as new y'. Finally we have 2 remaining directions, and choose one of them as new z'. That's $6\times 4 \times 2=48$.
In other words, I wrote down every kinds of permutions of (x,-x,y,-y,z,-z...) and assume that would be the subgroup of O(N) we need. I wonder if it's true for higher dimensions as my intuition doesn’t work. Or is there other method to write down the "Cubic group" in higher dimensions?

This is math, no physic, so move it to math.

The generalization is that the symmetry group of an $n$-dimensional cube has order $2^n \cdot n!$. This group can be precisely identified as the wreath product $(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)^n \rtimes S_n$, also known as a signed permutation group.
Using your description in your final paragraph, one can deduce this as follows.
Your group, which I'll denote $G_n$, is the group of permutations of the "signed" coordinates $(-x_1,x_1,-x_2,x_2,-x_3,x_3,...,-x_n,x_n)$ such that subscripts are preserved, in the sense that if $x_i$ goes to $x_j^{\pm 1}$ then $x_i^{-1}$ goes to $x_j^{\mp 1}$. This gives a well-defined permutation of the index set $\{1,...,n\}$, and that defines a homomorphism $G_n \mapsto S_n$.
The kernel of this homomorphism consists of all permutations taking the subset $\{-x_i,x_i\}$ to itself for all $i=1,...,n$, which is the direct sum of $n$ copies of the order $2$ cyclic group, that is, $(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)^n$.
Finally, we get the semidirect product structure by mapping each permutation $\sigma$ of the set $\{1,...,n\}$ to the signed permutation defined by $x_i \mapsto x_{\sigma(i)}$, $x_i^{-1} \mapsto x_{\sigma(i)}^{-1}$ for all $i=1,...,n$.

You might think about how many ways there are to orient a cube with all its vertices in fixed positions. The symmetry group moves one orientation to another.
The cube has $8$ vertices. You can place the first vertex in $8$ positions, the second in $7$, etc. This gives $8!$ permutations of the vertices. But we need to restrict ourselves to ones that leave all the edges the same.
Pick a vertex of a cube. Paint it blue. If you rotate the cube, there are $8$ places you can put the blue vertex.
Pick an adjacent vertex. Paint it green. The blue vertex is the end point of $3$ edges. There are $3$ possible positions for the green vertex. This means there are $24$ orientations the cube can reach through rotation.
Choose another vertex connected to the blue vertex and paint it green. There are two possible places it could be, but you cannot reach both with rotations. You can invert the cube to move it to the other possibility. This gives $48$ orientations.
We have now found all the orientations that leave the blue vertex with the same edges. Each of these was reached through rotation and inversion operations that prescribe the new positions of every vertex.
There is no symmetry operation you can do that would leave the vertices connected to blue fixed and still change other vertices. So we have the full symmetry group.
Note that $48 = 2^3 \cdot 3!$

Moving up to $4$D space, it gets complicated fast. But naively there are $16$ places for the blue vertex.
There are $4$ edges connected to the blue vertex, so there are $4$ positions for the green vertex.
Paint another blue-adjacent vertex rad. There are $3$ positions it could occupy. And $2$ for an orange vertex.
The total number of orientations would seem to be $2^4 \cdot 4! = 384$. But this doesn't show that all of these really leave all the edges with the correct endpoints or not. Nor that this exhausts all possible symmetry operations.

You might want to think about this in terms of symmetry operations like rotations and inversions.
When you rotate a $3$D cube, each of the vertices moves to a new position. When a point moves, it traces out a circular trajectory. A circle lies in a plane.
In $3$D space, there are $3$ mutually perpendicular axes. You line up the cube so the edges are parallel to the axes. Two axes define a plane parallel to a face of the cube. There are $3$ ways to pair up axes.
In $4$D, rotations are more complex. The axis is a plane. See Symmetry and the Fourth Dimension (Part 12)
For the full details about the rotational symmetries in $4$D, see Rotations in 4-dimensional Euclidean space

Every rotation takes place in a plane. 3D just has the unique property that the orthogonal complement to a plane is a line. It makes little sense to think about "rotation axes" in higher dimensions.

"But this doesn't show that all of these really leave all the edges with the correct endpoints or not. Nor that this exhausts all possible symmetry operations." That's what I'm confused too.

The point is that it has not yet been proved that "this exhausts all possible symmetry operations" of the cube, but it is nonetheless true and a proof can be found. For general $n$, the symmetry group of an $n$-dimensional cube has order $2^n \cdot n!$, and in fact this group can be precisely identified as the wreath product $(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)^n \rtimes S_n$, also known as the signed symmetric group.
